# How to create div opacity under (not over) other layer

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I styling my login page and I want to create a div opacity under the login form, but when I  do that, all layers inside it becomes opaque as well.

How to create a div opacity under other layer and not affecting its children?

P.S. currently using Tailwind in React

```
 <div className="max-w-[90%] w-[350px] bg-white p-8 rounded-xl opacity-50">
    <div>
      <img src={ logo } alt="Logo" />
      <label htmlFor="email">
        Email
        <input
          className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2
            px-3 text-grey-darker"
          id="email"
          type="email"
          placeholder="user@email.com"
        />
      </label>
      ...........
    </div>
 </div>
```

**Snippet:**

```css
body {
 background: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/top-view-table-full-of-food-picture-id1220017909?k=20&m=1220017909&s=170667a&w=0&h=4I_l8ZyiZ8sebPsRo6UpFmdrV-MZgEvxb3smE-TbgLE=') no-repeat center;
}

.login {
 background: white;
 opacity: 0.5;
 display: flex:
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 height: 200px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="login">
          <img src="https://image.similarpng.com/very-thumbnail/2021/09/Good-food-logo-design-on-transparent-background-PNG.png" width="100px" alt="Logo" />
          <label htmlFor="email">
            Email
            <input
              id="email"
              type="email"
              placeholder="user@email.com"
            />
          </label>
          <label htmlFor="email">
            Password
            <input
              id="password"
              type="password"
              placeholder="*******"
            />
          </label>
          <button type="button"> Enter </button>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lower the opacity of the background colour rather than the element itself.

Tailwind v2:

```
<div className="max-w-[90%] w-[350px] bg-white bg-opacity-50 p-8 rounded-xl">
```

[Documentation](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/background-opacity)

Tailwind v3:

```
<div className="max-w-[90%] w-[350px] bg-white/50 p-8 rounded-xl">
```

[Documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color#changing-the-opacity)

Comment: Thank you George! it worked V3!! I didn't know that !!

Answer (score 0):

You can Control the opacity of an element’s background color using the color opacity modifier

```
<div className="max-w-[90%] w-[350px] bg-white bg-opacity-50 ">
 ...

</div>
```

It goes from 0 to 100

Here's [more examples](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color#changing-the-opacity)